# how to insert amortization schedule in mysql in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops, amortization

I am using Laravel 5.7. I can create amortization schedule in Laravel view simply by using while loop in `php`.

Here is my code:

```php
//empty value error handling

// GETTING USER INPUTS AND ASSIGNING THEM TO VARIABLES
$amount = 98000000;
$interest = 8;
$year = 30;
$term = 12;

//creating period
$period = $term * $year;

if ($amount < 0) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Amount Can't be a Negative Value</p>";
}else if ($interest < 0) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Interest Cant't be a Negative Value</p>";
}else if ($year < 0 || $year > 50) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Loan repayment Years 1-50</p>";
}else if ($term<0) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Payment Periods can't be Negative</p>";
}else{
    $i = 0;
    $inter = ($interest / 100) / $term;
    while ($period !=0) {
        // making percentage in $interest
        //Creating the Denominator
        $deno = 1 - 1/pow((1+$inter),$period);
        
        //Payment for a period
        $payment = ($amount * $inter) / $deno;

        //Interest for a Period
        $periodInter = $amount*$inter;

        //Principal for a Period
        $principal = $payment - $periodInter;

        //Getting the Balance 
        $balance = $amount - $principal;
```

But I don't know how insert this loop result with multiple rows to MySQL database via controller?

Comment: Well, your final array must be assoc and  'column' => 'value', and each row in an array 
`Model::create(youArray)`..... 

`[ [ 'column' => 'value', 'column2' => 'value2' ]  ,  [ 'column' => 'value' , 'column2' => 'value2']  ]`

Comment: Please, don't take my comment as negative or anything similar, just as a small tip or constructive: please, if you are using Laravel, you need to [learn a lot about it](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x) and [PHP standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) too, your code is not using the framework not even 0.000001%, then why are you using Laravel ? There are a lot of good tutorials out there that explains the basics of PHP and Laravel so you can get running really fast.